# Cannot resolve symbol in package

Tags: intellij-idea, package

When I run the program, the following window opens[image]

What's the matter? I had this package in all previous projects and there were not any problems

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a module which classpath should be used for that run configuration - *Use classpath of module* setting

Comment: But I can't change something here. I have only one field to choose: https://imgur.com/a/jME8dAc

Comment: Looks like you didn't configure modules for your project, did you?